# Login authentication with axios and formik

Tags: reactjs, authentication, axios, formik

I'm new to using both axios and formik and likely making a simple mistake here.  I'm attempting to check if the user's email and password exists and has been typed correctly.  Upon authentication they should be logged in with useContext and then redirected to the homepage.

Currently, after submitting, the form simply remains greyed out without reaching the .then/.catch block.  Is it a problem with the way I typed the auth parameter?

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const authenticate = useContext(AuthContext);
  const [serverState, setServerState] = useState();
  const handleServerResponse = (ok, msg) => {
    setServerState({ok, msg});
  };
  const handleOnSubmit = (values, actions) => {
    axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/api/users/login",
      data: values,
      auth: {
        email,
        password
      }
    })
    .then(response => {
      actions.setSubmitting(false);
      actions.resetForm();
      handleServerResponse(true, "Logged In!");
    })
    .catch(error => {
      actions.setSubmitting(false);
      handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error);
    });
    authenticate.login();
    Router.push("/")
  };

  return (
    <Formik
      initialValues={{
        email: "",
        password: "",
      }}
      validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
        email: Yup.string(),
        password: Yup.string(),
      })}
      onSubmit={handleOnSubmit}
    >
      {({ isSubmitting }) => (
      <Form>
        <Field
          name="email"
          type="email"
          fullWidth
          component={TextField}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Email"
        />
        <Box pt={1}>
        <Field
          name="password"
          type="password"
          fullWidth
          component={TextField}
          variant="outlined"
          label="Password"
        />
        </Box>
        <Box pt={2}>
          <Button
            type="submit"
            variant="contained"
            fullWidth
            color="primary"
            disabled={isSubmitting}
          >
            Submit
          </Button>
          {serverState && (
          <Typography className={!serverState.ok ? "errorMsg" : ""}>
            {serverState.msg}
          </Typography>
        )}
        </Box>
      </Form>
      )}
    </Formik>
  );
};
```

The Node JS API on the backend:

```
const login = async (req, res, next) => {
  const { email, password } = req.body;

  let existingUser;

  try {
    existingUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
  } catch (err) {
    const error = new HttpError("Login failed, please try again later.", 500);
    return next(error);
  }

  if (!existingUser || existingUser.password !== password) {
    const error = new HttpError("Invalid credentials, login failed.", 401);
    return next(error);
  }

  res.json({ message: "Logged in!" });
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason why the form is grayed out is because you use `isSubmitting` and when you submit the form, it is set to `true`, but inside `handleOnSubmit`, you have an synchronous function, so you only call `actions.setSubmitting(false)` once the formik already think you finished the `onSubmit`.

Another way of doing this is to make `handleOnSubmit` return a promise and once the promise is resolved, formik will set `isSubmitting` to `false` automatically.

This is explained in [the docs](https://formik.org/docs/api/formik#onsubmit-values-values-formikbag-formikbag--void--promiseany)

> **IMPORTANT**: If `onSubmit` is `async`, then Formik will automatically set `isSubmitting` to `false` on your behalf once it has resolved. This means you do NOT need to call `formikBag.setSubmitting(false)` manually. However, if your `onSubmit` function is synchronous, then you need to call `setSubmitting(false)` on your own.

So what I recomendo you to do and solve your problem is make `handleOnSubmit` an `async` method and return the axios call (return a promise) or use `await`.

An example of that would be something like

```
const handleOnSubmit = (values, actions) => {
  // returning a promise
  return axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:5000/api/users/login",
    data: values,
    auth: {
      email,
      password
    }
  })
  .then(response => {
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    actions.resetForm();
    handleServerResponse(true, "Logged In!");
  })
  .catch(error => {
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error);
  });

  // this shouldn't be outside the .then/.catch
  // if you are going to use .then/.catch, put the above line inside it
  // authenticate.login();
  // Router.push("/")
};
```

Or with `async`/`await`

```
//               using async
const handleOnSubmit = async (values, actions) => {

  //           using await in the axios call
  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/api/users/login",
      data: values,
      auth: {
        email,
        password
      }
    })
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    actions.resetForm();
    handleServerResponse(true, "Logged In!");
  } catch(error) {
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error);
  }
  authenticate.login();
  Router.push("/")
};
```

Comment: I converted it into a try/catch block with async/await and that does allow it to submit; however it's still not authenticating and returning to the home page.  It seems to be a problem with the auth object but I'm not sure what.

Comment: @TommyBeard The problem is probably in the node js api, but it's hard to know why it doesn't go into the `.then`/`.catch` because it depends on the values of the form and what happens when you call `next(error)`. Because if there is an error and you never call something like `res.json()` to return to the front end. So probably there is an error and your api is never return to the front end, the request just hangs there

Answer (score 0):

So what I recommend you to do and solve your problem is to make handle On Submit an async method and return the await.

```
const handleOnSubmit = async (values, actions) => {

  try {
    const response = await axios({
      method: "POST",
      url: "http://localhost:5000/api/users/login",
      data: values,
      auth: {
        email,
        password
      }
    })
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    actions.resetForm();
    handleServerResponse(true, "Logged In!");
  } catch(error) {
    actions.setSubmitting(false);
    handleServerResponse(false, error.response.data.error);
  }
  authenticate.login();
  Router.push("/")
};
```